# JQuery getJSON method not being called

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a table with pagination using jQuery and json but can't get the `getJSON` method to work. The JavaScript function `GetPageData` is called on page load and is being called successfully. I've tested adding the two commented out lines in the code below and can see that no code inside of the `getJSON` method has any effect.

```js
function GetPageData(pageNum, pageSize) {
    $("#tblData").empty();
    $("#paged").empty();
   // $("#tblData").append('<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>')
    $.getJSON("/Retailers/GetPagedData", { pageNumber: pageNum, pageSize: pageSize }, function (response) {
     //   $("#tblData").append('<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>')
        var rowData = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < response.Data.length; i++) {
            rowData = rowData + '<tr><td>' + response.Data[i].Name + '</td><td>' + response.Data[i].RetailerCode + '</td></tr>';
        }
        rowData = rowData + '<tr><td>Name</td><td>RetailerCode</td></tr>';
        $("#tblData").append(rowData);
        PagingTemplate(response.TotalPages, response.CurrentPage);
    });
```

Below is the Index.cshtml view, which is in the Retailers folder.

```html
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Manage Retailers";
}
<p class="h2">Manage Retailers</p>
<br /><br />
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Retailer Name</th>
            <th>Retailer Code</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tblData"></tbody>
</table>
<div id="paged"></div>
```

and below is the RetailersController...

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CCM.Models;
using CCM.Helper;

namespace CCM.Controllers
{
    public class RetailersController : Controller
    {
        MCDevEntities context = new MCDevEntities();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult GetPagedData(int pageNumber = 1, int pageSize = 20)
        {
            List<Retailer> listData = context.Retailers.ToList();
            var pagedData = Pagination.PagedResult(listData, pageNumber, pageSize);
            return Json(pagedData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything obvious that could be stopping this from working? I also have a Helper folder containing PagedData.cs and Pagination.cs. The page URL is localhost:.../Retailers/Index.

Edit.

In case it helps here is the rest of the javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Initially load pagenumber=1, pagesize=20
    GetPageData(1, 20);
});

function PagingTemplate(totalPage, currentPage) {
    var template = "";
    var TotalPages = totalPage;
    var CurrentPage = currentPage;
    var PageNumberArray = Array();


    var countIncr = 1;
    for (var i = currentPage; i <= totalPage; i++) {
        PageNumberArray[0] = currentPage;
        if (totalPage != currentPage && PageNumberArray[countIncr - 1] != totalPage) {
            PageNumberArray[countIncr] = i + 1;
        }
        countIncr++;
    };
    PageNumberArray = PageNumberArray.slice(0, 5);
    var FirstPage = 1;
    var LastPage = totalPage;
    if (totalPage != currentPage) {
        var ForwardOne = currentPage + 1;
    }
    var BackwardOne = 1;
    if (currentPage > 1) {
        BackwardOne = currentPage - 1;
    }

    template = "<p>" + CurrentPage + " of " + TotalPages + " pages</p>"
    template = template + '<ul class="pager">' +
        '<li class="previous"><a href="#" onclick="GetPageData(' + FirstPage + ')"><i class="fa fa-fast-backward"></i>&nbsp;First</a></li>' +
        '<li><select ng-model="pageSize" id="selectedId"><option value="20" selected>20</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option><option value="150">150</option></select> </li>' +
        '<li><a href="#" onclick="GetPageData(' + BackwardOne + ')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></i></a>';

    var numberingLoop = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < PageNumberArray.length; i++) {
        numberingLoop = numberingLoop + '<a class="page-number active" onclick="GetPageData(' + PageNumberArray[i] + ')" href="#">' + PageNumberArray[i] + ' &nbsp;&nbsp;</a>'
    }
    template = template + numberingLoop + '<a href="#" onclick="GetPageData(' + ForwardOne + ')" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></i></a></li>' +
        '<li class="next"><a href="#" onclick="GetPageData(' + LastPage + ')">Last&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-fast-forward"></i></a></li></ul>';
    $("#paged").append(template);
    $('#selectedId').change(function () {
        GetPageData(1, $(this).val());
    });
}
```

Comment: did you tried $.get() instead of $.getJSON() ?

Comment: thanks for yor suggestion, I have tried this now and it appears to make no difference, the code in the $.get() has no effect.

Comment: can you try to include the parameters into the URL? `/Retailers/GetPagedData?pageNumber=1&pageSize=20`
And remove this `{ pageNumber: pageNum, pageSize: pageSize }` from the `$.getJSON` method.

Comment: replacing the line `$.getJSON("/Retailers/GetPagedData", { pageNumber: pageNum, pageSize: pageSize }, function (response) {` with `$.get("/Retailers/Index/GetPagedData?pageNumber=1&pageSize=20", function (response) {` now causes the code inside the method to run but only the initial append and not the table data unfortunately. I'm also unsure if this approach will cause a page load, which is what I am trying to avoid. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you check to see if your get request is going through in the network tab of your console?

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't know to look there. It is there with a status code 500 - "`A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Retailer_B96AF7...`". I tried adding the following line in the getJSON but it didn't seem to help: `"db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;"`

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/Retailers/GetPagedData',
            data: {
                pageNumber: pageNum,
                pageSize: pageSize
            },
            success: function (response) {
                //code
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Ajit, I've tried this now but the same thing happens, the table data is not loaded and in the network tab of the console is the following: `Server Error in '/' Application.
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Retailer_B96A...`. The request URL it tried to send is the same: `http://localhost:.../Retailers/GetPagedData?pageNumber=1&pageSize=20` and manually putting this in the URL returns the error to screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and check:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetPagedData", "Retailers")',
        data: {pageNumber : pageNum,
            pageSize: pageSize 
        },
        success: function (response) {
             console.log(response);
            //   $("#tblData").append('<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>')
            var rowData = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < response.Data.length; i++) {
                rowData = rowData + '<tr><td>' + response.Data[i].Name + '</td><td>' + response.Data[i].RetailerCode + '</td></tr>';
            }
            rowData = rowData + '<tr><td>Name</td><td>RetailerCode</td></tr>';
            $("#tblData").append(rowData);
            PagingTemplate(response.TotalPages, response.CurrentPage);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately the data didn't populate using this code and checking the network tab I can see it had the same error mentioned above. I changed "Retailers" to "Retailers/Index" in your code and that avoided the error. Uncommenting the test line in the code did populate the table with the test data but the actual data did not get inserted. I'm wondering if there is an issue with my model.

Comment: Updated the code to log the result from controller. Check the result in console and see what it shows?

Comment: Thanks, I get "`TypeError: response.Data is undefined`". It appears response is not null but response.Data is null.

Comment: So the error is in your controller not in JavaScript. Fix it and you are good to go.